# Mesh to block or reduce wireless cell signals

Tags: wireless, emf, faraday-cage

I want to block or reduce the amount of wireless cell signals coming into my house through my window(s) by using some type of mesh (screen).  I could use a sheet of metal but then I wouldn't be able to see through the window.  I am initially planning on standard window screen made of aluminum (not fiberglass), and I would ground the screen to an earth ground outside my house.  The wireless signals are from a new cell tower across the street from my house.  It has 3G, 4G and is supposed to get 5G.  So the frequencies I believe would be 850MHz-1.9GHz for 3G, 700MHz-2.6GHz for 4G and 2.5-30GHz for 5G.  **What would be, or how would I calculate the maximum hole size to block these signals?**  **Does the thickness of the screen matter?**  Would I be trying to interfere with the frequencies or the amplitudes of these signals?  PS: My house has metal siding but the roof is asphalt.  My EMF meter typically has higher readings throughout the house the higher it is to the ceiling.  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put down the EMF meter.  Ignore it.  Worry about things that matter, like your friends and family.  Your EMF meter is an uncalibrated toy, suitable only for creating fear and concern where none should exist.

Comment: Block the signals for what purpose?

Comment: Because it has been scientifically proven that wireless signals have an adverse effect on our bodies.  This non-ionizing radiation has different effects as ionizing radiation, but it still has adverse effects.

Comment: Wireless signals have **not** "been scientifically proven that wireless signals have an adverse effect on our bodies."  You'll have to cite something better than the advertisement for your EMF meter.

Comment: Where is it proven? By whom? If it is proven dangerous, why they are not banned yet?

Comment: Perhaps your windows admit sunlight. A *visible radiation* detector should cause you much more concern.

Comment: The mesh in aluminum screening should be small enough to effectively shield all the frequencies up to 30 GHz. You should probably get a spectrum analyzer, though, and test to see what frequencies are present and at what levels inside your home. You don't need to earth ground the screens. They will be reflecting the RF, not shorting it to ground.

Comment: Thank you mkeith for answering my questions.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover your paint question as well.

Comment: If non-ionizing radiation was proven to have an adverse effect on humans, it would be banned very quickly.

Comment: The OP stated a well formulated question. We should try to help answer it, or discuss the merits, but not judge it with slap-down-votes.

Comment: Thank you P2000 once again!  And for the naysayers... just a quick note... "The NTP study shows that biological hazards from RF Microwave radiation exposures occur at levels far below that which would cause tissue heating and far below current FCC RF Microwave radiation exposure guidelines."  https://scientists4wiredtech.com/2017/12/nasa-engineer-letter-to-editor/.  The NTP study was on radio frequency radiation used by cell phones.  The wireless telecom industry does not like this information to be known, nor the FCC.  The FCC is filled with former telecom employees.  Enough said.

Comment: If the non-ionizing radiation from the sun cannot affect humans, then the even lower power RF radiation wont. You body is radiating infrared all the time and infrared has way higher energy photons that RF.

Comment: Your taking the credibility of the NTP study as higher than the FCC, basically all modern scientists and logic.

Comment: The NTP Study was not performed in someones basement.  I often prefer independent scientists and doctors, not the FCC $ scientists and doctors.  1,670 Peer-Reviewed Scientific Papers on Electromagnetic Fields and Biology or Health @ https://drive.google.com/file/d/19CbWmdGTnnW1iZ9pxlxq1ssAdYl3Eur3/view

Comment: @Ahmed Eshra As for scientists and doctors... "We the undersigned scientists, doctors, environmental organizations and citizens from (__) countries, urgently call for a halt to the deployment of the 5G (fifth generation) wireless network, including 5G from space satellites. 5G will massively increase exposure to radio frequency (RF) radiation on top of the 2G, 3G and 4G networks for telecommunications already in place. RF radiation has been proven harmful for humans and the environment. The deployment of 5G constitutes an experiment on humanity"...  https://www.5gspaceappeal.org/the-appeal

Comment: Also another website that isn't proven, where are the peer reviewed, established, repeatable modern research articles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mesh attenuates in the range 10dB to 50dB. For anything more than that you'd need sheets of 1mm to 2mm thick, made of copper or steel.

It is not true that holes smaller than the wavelength block or shield an EM wave. Also, findings of the Faraday cage -not box- for electrostatic fields (familiar to many from Physics classes) are often misleadingly extrapolated to electromagnetic fields.

Brick, wood, cladding all attenuate but do not shield, so it's not just your windows but also the walls, blank doors.

Metal chimneys and vents will also guide waves inward.

When testing our RF circuits we use a shielded chamber, made of copper plate. Even the door has a copper coil, installed like a draft stop. It provides more than 100dB attenuation, which is adequate to perform sensitive noise measurements in our circuits. Supply and network cables leading into the chamber are throttled with chokes.

Cell towers transmit at 40dBm or more. That's one transmitter at one frequency. Add a few up, at different bands, and from different towers, and you can see how an attenuation of 20dB does not accomplish much if you are close to the source.

As for your question, here are some examples of materials with attenuations higher than mesh.

https://aaronia.com/shielding-materials/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwhb36BRCfARIsAKcXh6FF4fIEuC859ZNxsboV7l0x20du8nL3yp8NBj_2bn1OHYt-71i8ZBwaAo3jEALw_wcB

From an engineering standpoint I'd say you will be throwing too little money at a problem for which there is too little evidence.

You pointed to a shielding paint. The manufacturer, Yshield (Germany), reports their in-house RF tests with 40dB attenuation after 1 coat, and 50dB & 60dB after resp. 2 & 3 coats. These are notable numbers.

https://slt.co/Downloads/Shared/YSHIELD-HSF54-DB2020.pdf

For 60dB, $230 covers perhaps 150 sqft of wall/ceiling. Do the math for your home: a 2000 sqft 2-story home has 3400 sqft of surface needing coverage, and costs $5200 (very ball-park).

This is the attenuation through the paint, and does not account for imperfections in a realistic space (doors, windows, other orifices etc..)

Another issue is entrapment of EM waves: whatever gets in, or originates from within, is reflected between walls until it decays away. With purely reflective protection there is no EM escape. The report does not split the attenuation between absorption and reflection, but they do quote the resistivity. Absorbers would be the carbon paint, the furniture etc. and -ironically- human bodies.

You still need to cover the windows, which require a metallic foil. Metallic heat and UV shields also provide EM attenuation. Some office buildings with darkened windows are notorious for poor cell phone reception inside. (And I don't believe the foil is grounded)

The supplier you mention has those as well:

https://slt.co/Products/RFShieldingPaint/ShieldingPaint-YShield-HSF54.aspx

Comment: This is a good answer. But 20 dB of attenuation is pretty substantial. Nothing to be scoffed at from an exposure perspective.

Comment: 40 dBm is 10 Watts. 20 dBm is 0.1 Watts.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, agreed.  Also note that the first meter (!) in free space, at 1GHz and above, is already at least 30dB attenuation. I'm just making an esoteric point that if someone is worried about EMI, then 20dB around a cell tower is not much cushion & comfort.

Comment: @P2000 & mkeith Thank you for your answers.  I will look into the examples posted.  There is a paint (for the walls and ceiling) which claims to attenuate radio frequencies (as perhaps mentioned in another post about guitar pickups).  It is black and is carbon based and needs to be grounded, "provides protection against RF radiation, microwave and also from low-frequency electric fields if grounded properly".  It claims an attenuation of 39 dB. It is expensive.  Do you two think there is truth to the claim?  https://slt.co/Products/RFShieldingPaint/ShieldingPaint-YShield-HSF54.aspx

Comment: I don't know. It is possible to make conductive paint that can help shield against EM waves. But the paints I have seen were all metallic, not carbon-based. I doubt any thin substance will be effective at blocking or shielding low frequency EM waves or fields. It may be possible for a carbon based coating to absorb radiation also, but I believe it would need to be thick. In anechoic chambers, it is common to use carbon impregnated foam pads to absorb EM waves. But they have a LOT of carbon in them.

Comment: Thank you P2000 and mkeith for answering my question.  You two are a breath of fresh air in a smoke cloud of naysayers.  Since the paint is to be grounded, it would seem it absorbs rather than reflects.  My house is wired... no wireless router, no wireless keyboard, no cordless phone, no wireless TV, disabled everything wireless.  No microwave oven... try using an EMF meter while a microwave oven is operating, at 10 feet away the EMF's are horribly high!  The detector the Sears tech. uses is, well, useless in my view.  My home environment was rather EMF clean until that cell tower was built.

Comment: I live in an apartment building and I constantly see about 10+ WiFi signals from my neighbors (I don't use WiFi myself), at least ~5 of them appears full strength.  I wonder if painting the main walls would have a great effect?  How thorough does the job need to be until I can't see my neighbors' WiFi signals?

Comment: @YanKingYin I can receive WiFi inside a metal transportation container converted to a storage space, just through cracks and ventilation holes, so yes this is very difficult.